# LIKE comparison in SQL Server XML datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a DB table with an XML datatype column. The column contains values like this:

```
<NameValuePairCollection>
  <NameValuePair Name="Foo" Value="One" />
  <NameValuePair Name="Bar" Value="Two" />
  <NameValuePair Name="Baz" Value="Three" />
</NameValuePairCollection>
```

I am trying to query for all rows where the XML datatype column has a value of `"One"` for `"Foo"`. I am having trouble creating the appropriate XQuery to filter the results.

I found a couple related SO questions which helped me in my attempt but I still can't get it to work.

[How can I query a value in SQL Server XML column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10344553/346561)
[Use a LIKE statment on SQL Server XML Datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832987/346561)

Here is the SQL I have so far:

```
select * 
from MyTable 
where [XmlDataColumn].value('((/NameValuePairCollection/NameValuePair)[@Name="Foo"])[@Value]', 'varchar(max)') = 'One'
order by ID desc
```

Here is the error I am getting right now:

```
XQuery [MyTable.XmlDataColumn.value()]: Cannot atomize/apply data() on expression that contains type 'NameValuePair' within inferred type 'element(NameValuePair,#anonymous) *'
```

**UPDATE** (in response to @LeoWörteler's suggestion)

Based on your answer, I changed my SQL to this:

```
select * 
from MyTable with(nolock) 
where [XmlDataColumn].value('/NameValuePairCollection/NameValuePair[@Name="Subject"]/@Value', 'varchar(max)') = 'One'
order by ID desc
```

This still doesn't work though. I get the following error:

```
XQuery [MyTable.XmlDataColumn.value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xs:string *'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a LIKE statement on SQL Server XML Datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832987/use-a-like-statement-on-sql-server-xml-datatype)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select the value of the `Value` attribute instead of the whole `NameValuePair` element with the XPath expression in `[XmlDataColumn].value(...)`, this should work:

```
/NameValuePairCollection/NameValuePair[@Name="Foo"]/@Value
```

Your expression only checks if the `NameValuePair` has an attribute `Value`.

If there are multiple elements with the correct name and you want to check if any of them has the value `"One"`, you can use the [`exist(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) method:

```
where [XmlDataColumn].exist(
  '/NameValuePairCollection/NameValuePair[@Name="Subject" and @Value="One"]') = 1
```

Comment: I tried this but it still didn't work. See the edit to my question for more details.

Comment: Are there multiple `NameValuePair`s with the `Name` you are looking for? I'll update my answer for that case.

Comment: I don't think there were multiple elements with the same `Name` but I will try your alternate solution and see what happens.

Comment: I must have records where there are multiple `NameValuePair` elements that have a "Name" attribute of `"Foo"` because your second solution worked for me. Thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to cast the XML as varchar, and then search for the given string as if the XML vas a varchar field.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE CAST(Column as nvarchar(max)) LIKE '%Name="Foo" Value="One"%'
```

I love this solution as it is clean, easy to remember, hard to mess up, and can be used as a part of a where clause.

It's not as dynamic and complete as the answer provided by Leo, but depending on the circumstances it can be a "quick n' dirty" way to get the data needed.