# Like Search on XML fields - sql server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a XML data field in my table (Sql server 2008 R2) where I am saving XML of my product metadata. Below is the format of xml. There could be different numbers of metadata associated with products hence no fixed format.

```
<Item>
      <Profile>170</Profile>
      <Type>1</Type>
      <InterfaceType DefaultImage="">Product</InterfaceType>
      <Metadatas>
        <Metadata>
          <Control>2ad9cf19-2a88-4b6c-9f59-28e177679d2a</Control>
          <ControlTypeID>5ae9a004-c0de-4692-a9bd-e8f73926f4f3</ControlTypeID>
          <Name>QA Category</Name>
          <Value>test</value>
          <ControlDatas />
        </Metadata>
        <Metadata>
          <Control>8504787e-f502-4e7a-9313-3257df10b554</Control>
          <ControlTypeID>5ae9a004-c0de-4692-a9bd-e8f73926f4f3</ControlTypeID>
          <Name>AS240 Desc</Name>
          <Value>240</value>
          <ControlDatas />
        </Metadata>
        <Metadata>
          <Control>97927910-234c-4827-b7c7-3bcb21dc2a88</Control>
          <ControlTypeID>5ae9a004-c0de-4692-a9bd-e8f73926f4f3</ControlTypeID>
          <Name>Resolution</Name>
          <Value>40</value>
          <ControlDatas />
        </Metadata>
        <Metadata>
          <Control>e3d7a5c8-c8e0-4c44-97ff-4ea290df1c34</Control>
          <ControlTypeID>5ae9a004-c0de-4692-a9bd-e8f73926f4f3</ControlTypeID>
          <Name>Business Center</Name>
          <Value>chicago</value>
          <ControlDatas />
        </Metadata>
        <Metadata>
          <Control>1e3674ec-0b9f-4faa-9454-52c293b8d389</Control>
          <ControlTypeID>f9966e48-3cf0-47f5-a602-0e47d6bc445c</ControlTypeID>
          <Name>QA Spec Status</Name>
          <Value>1</Value>
          <ControlDatas />
        </Metadata>
        <Metadata>
          <Control>d96d3390-63de-414d-869a-9e0243ff4cbc</Control>
          <ControlTypeID>5ae9a004-c0de-4692-a9bd-e8f73926f4f3</ControlTypeID>
          <Name>QA Manager</Name>
          <Value />
          <ControlDatas />
        </Metadata>
        <Metadata>
          <Control>a0fe9e68-c45c-49e2-8385-9f99f1d9e5fe</Control>
          <ControlTypeID>5ae9a004-c0de-4692-a9bd-e8f73926f4f3</ControlTypeID>
          <Name>Product Quality Manager</Name>
          <Value />
          <ControlDatas />
        </Metadata>
        <Metadata>
          <Control>b72dd25e-ac2b-4eca-b59c-b2caec2c0e92</Control>
          <ControlTypeID>5ae9a004-c0de-4692-a9bd-e8f73926f4f3</ControlTypeID>
          <Name>GTIN</Name>
          <Value />
          <ControlDatas />
        </Metadata>
        <Metadata>
          <Control>d9df10f0-a82f-4ba2-96f5-b71774a521c9</Control>
          <ControlTypeID>c349aa0e-9c1d-406a-9eb9-b9ad5e561300</ControlTypeID>
          <Name>Item Creation Date</Name>
          <Value>27/04/2013 12:00:00 AM</Value>
          <ControlDatas />
        </Metadata>
        <Metadata>
          <Control>dd6e875d-34b7-4b79-bb65-c3608f81f754</Control>
          <ControlTypeID>f9966e48-3cf0-47f5-a602-0e47d6bc445c</ControlTypeID>
          <Name>SUPC Status</Name>
          <Value>active</Value>
          <ControlDatas />
        </Metadata>
        <Metadata>
          <Control>a2682372-664b-4ee0-9a72-d69965c9be9f</Control>
          <ControlTypeID>5ae9a004-c0de-4692-a9bd-e8f73926f4f3</ControlTypeID>
          <Name>Qa Spec Desc</Name>
          <Value />
          <ControlDatas />
        </Metadata>
        <Metadata>
          <Control>5c4f7fa4-f56b-4d91-a0dc-ead6f8115020</Control>
          <ControlTypeID>5ae9a004-c0de-4692-a9bd-e8f73926f4f3</ControlTypeID>
          <Name>Brand</Name>
          <Value>Sysco</Value>
          <ControlDatas />
        </Metadata>
        <Metadata>
          <Control>52fc415d-b844-472c-82d9-f205a9104825</Control>
          <ControlTypeID>5ae9a004-c0de-4692-a9bd-e8f73926f4f3</ControlTypeID>
          <Name>UPC</Name>
          <Value />
          <ControlDatas />
        </Metadata>
      </Metadatas>
    </Item>
```

I want to do a like search on the values of the metadata which are stored in value tag in metadata tag. I am successfully able to do a exact search on string by doing search on

```
<Name>QA Category</Name>
<Value>test</value>
```

is there a way to do like search on value tag? There could be millions of product records in database.

Answer (score 0):

query() – Used to extract XML fragments from an XML data type.

value() – Used to extract a single value from an XML document.

exist() – Used to determine if a specified node exists. Returns 1 if yes and 0 if no.

modify() – Updates XML data in an XML data type.

node() – Shreds XML data into multiple rows (not covered in this blog post).

you can do something like:
[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832987/use-a-like-statment-on-sql-server-xml-datatype)

```
SELECT * 
FROM WebPageContent 
WHERE data.value('(/Item/Text)[1]', 'varchar(100)') LIKE 'XYZ%'
```

OR

You can use something like:

```
where XMLField.exist('/Item/someitems/Name[.="QA Category"]')=1
```

As you have lots of records, i would suggest you to create xml index on that column to improve performence

Here is very good article by pinal on [xml based searching](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/27/sql-server-introduction-to-discovering-xml-data-type-methods-a-primer/)..

Another [good article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-xml-methods-in-sql-server/)